# What are the new Biomes for Terraria 1.2?

Tags: terraria

So far, I've found Crimson, I've found Snow, and I've found an underground Pyramid, but are there any other Biomes that have been added to the game as of update 1.2?  And if so, what do they have to offer?  Are there any new Hardmode Biomes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New biomes in 1.2 are

- Rain Biome (Looks like a forest but has a chance to rain)
- The Crimson
- Underground Crimson
- Crimson Desert
- Lihzahrd Temple (The pyramid in the Underground Jungle)
- Living Tree (Large trees that may be hollow and contain chests and furniture)
- Corrupted Living Tree
- Spider Nest
- Underground Snow

Comment: This is all I could think of and find confirmation for

Answer (score -1):

Your forgetting some of the best biomes available:

- Rain Biome
- Moon Biome
- Spider Nest
- Living Tree
- Underground Crimson
- Underground Snow
- Lihzard Temple

You've listed:

- Crimson biome
- Snow biome

The pyramid isn't technically it's own biome. Just a desert. Water now changes in these biomes and much more. You can read more about it [here](http://www.pcgamer.com/2013/10/02/terraria-1-2-update-released-tweaks-almost-every-part-of-the-game/).

Comment: Rain is a biome?  I thought it was a random event.

Comment: There are many more new biomes than this.

Comment: Where did you find a moon biome?

Comment: @3ventic in a video.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a mod?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Zibbobz it could also be the joke video of a biome painted all white and claimed to be a moon biome